# Grails rendering plugins

Tags: css, rendering, grails-plugin

I'm using grails rendering to render table into the pdf. when column data is more that data is not getting break(i.e it should get fixed into that column only) I have used "word-break: break-all" property but it is not working at all.
E.g

```
    <div style="text-align:center;word-break: break-all">
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
</div>
```

Comment: I can't understand what the problem is. Can you post some code?

Comment: Please add the code

Comment: Did you disable word wrapping? Did you set overflow to hidden? We need more to go off of.

Comment: @ Night5h4d3 i have not disable the word wrapping.

Comment: I tried everything but it is not working in the rendering plugin.

Answer (score 0):

without space the whole thing is a word and we have to break the word to make it wrapped. use `word-wrap: break-word;`. Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: i have tried this also but it does not the problem at all.

Comment: have a look on this fiddle, i think it is solved. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tuku/3fmb8p0d/1/)

Comment: True But it not working in grails rendering plugin css.